# How to install Python 2.7 bindings for OpenCV using MacPorts

Tags: python, opencv, osx-lion, macports

When trying to "import cv" in python I get: "ImportError: No module named cv". This question has appeared in many forms, but I haven't found the answer that helps.

On my Mac OS X Lion, among many other ports, I have run:

```
sudo port install python27
```

and

```
sudo port install opencv +python27
```

Running:

```
port select python
```

I see: "python27 (active)"

And running:

```
port installed opencv
```

I see: "opencv @2.3.1a_1+python27 (active)"

What else should I check?  Thanks.

Comment: Should I find cv.so in: `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`? It's not there...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had this same problem. It looks like a (maybe?) bug with the OpenCV install script for 2.3.1a.  It will not create the Python bindings unless NumPy is already installed.

To fix it:

```
sudo port uninstall opencv
sudo port install py27-numpy
sudo port install opencv +python27
```

That worked for me!  I found this by doing some Googling, and the correct answer was here:
wbarczynski.org/wp/2011/11/25/opencv-with-py-bindings-on-mac-with-macports-intall-numpy-first/

Comment: Thanks a lot; this worked!

In particular I ran: `sudo port uninstall opencv @2.3.1a_1+python27`
`sudo port uninstall opencv @2.3.1a_1`
`sudo port install py27-numpy`
`sudo port install opencv +python27`

Comment: I was then able to run `import cv` in python.

Comment: I did port install py27-numpy

Comment: This also worked for me. For me, I installed numpy using both macports and pip before. So that might be causing the problem. So I uninstalled numpy with pip. Then did what was suggested and everything worked. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. @pyan, it worked for me to (1) install numpy and cv2 with pip, (2) install opencv 3.1 with the Python 2.7 bindings. I did not have to replace the pip-based numpy by a MacPorts one.

Answer (score 2):

**STEP ONE**

Use Macports to install opencv.

**STEP TWO**

Put these two files somewhere on your `PYTHONPATH` (for example in your `site-packages`):

- https://github.com/jonmrodriguez/opencv-2.3-new-python-bindings/blob/master/cv.py
- https://github.com/jonmrodriguez/opencv-2.3-new-python-bindings/blob/master/cv2.so

**STEP THREE**

Create the below soft links (because `cv2.so` expects the dylibs to be in `/usr/local` but MacPorts installs to `/opt/local`):

```
cd /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.3.dylib libopencv_core.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_flann.2.3.dylib libopencv_flann.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.3.dylib libopencv_imgproc.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_video.2.3.dylib libopencv_video.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_ml.2.3.dylib libopencv_ml.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.2.3.dylib libopencv_features2d.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.3.dylib libopencv_highgui.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.2.3.dylib libopencv_calib3d.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.2.3.dylib libopencv_objdetect.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.2.3.dylib libopencv_legacy.2.3.dylib
ln -s /opt/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.2.3.dylib libopencv_contrib.2.3.dylib
```

Comment: I did _not_ need to carry out steps two and three in order to get the python bindings working properly.  Thanks.

Comment: Hm. I wonder why my environment required that. Surely some prior install of some conflict.

Comment: I followed your suggestions above, and I am not getting an ImportError.  Unfortunately the opencv module is failing (Process finished with exit code 139).

Comment: I did a try:
        import cv2
    except ImportError:
        print "cv2 is not installed" exit()
    print "looks like it is installed" exit()   but it crashed with the error 139 without giving any output whatsoever.

Answer (score -2):

I was wondering if you have installed opencv to the OSX version of the python instead of macports.

have you tried easy install, I normally use easy_install to install the packages.

```
/opt/local/bin/easy_install-2.7 opencv
```

Comment: I do see all the libopencv_*.dylib files in /opt/local/lib, which I believe is where MacPorts would have installed them. Would installing using your suggestion write over or conflict with the MacPorts install?  And would easy_install include the python bindings? Thanks.

Comment: so its your choice, to pick which python version you want to use. I use MacPorts installation. Respect to python bindings I haven't had any problem using any packages after installing as I mentioned above.

Comment: I have only been using MacPorts so far.  I did try    `sudo /opt/local/bin/easy_install-2.7 opencv`    but I got an error:    `Searching for opencv    
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/opencv/    
Couldn't find index page for 'opencv' (maybe misspelled?)    
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)  
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/  
No local packages or download links found for opencv  
error: Could not find suitable distribution for     Requirement.parse('opencv')  
`