# Can't get OpenCV to work with Python on a Mac

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, osx-snow-leopard, macports

I am having trouble getting OpenCV to work with Python on my Mac.

I have tried installing it with MacPorts and with Cmake (which I installed from MacPorts) using the methods found at here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port. I also had to download Xcode to make MacPorts work.

I ran `sudo port -v install opencv +python27` and it seemed to work fine. However when I tried to import OpenCV in Python using `import cv`, the module could not be found.

If any of this information helps, I have OSX 10.6.8 Snow Leopard, python 2.7.3, and am trying to install OpenCV 2.4.3. I am not a very experienced programmer so my troubleshooting attempts are falling short of a solution.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, the instructions you have linked are very old so it is no wonder they will not work for opencv 2.4.3. You should look for newer instructions but I do not know if they exist.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the MacPorts installation, but you might want to try this:

```
import cv2
from cv2.cv import *
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it seems that the OpenCV Python Bindings don't get installed without `numpy` preinstalled; you can use these commands:

```
sudo port uninstall opencv
sudo port install py27-numpy
sudo port install opencv +python27
```

As in this question: [How to install Python 2.7 bindings for OpenCV using MacPorts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410443/how-to-install-python-2-7-bindings-for-opencv-using-macports)