# Importing opencv with Python

Tags: python, opencv

using this post: [How to install Python 2.7 bindings for OpenCV using MacPorts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410443/how-to-install-python-2-7-bindings-for-opencv-using-macports) for reference I installed opencv and numpy with

```
sudo port install numpy
sudo port install opencv +python27
```

This seemed to work, but if I do

```
import cv
```

in a python file and try to run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv
ImportError: No module named cv
```

That post is a couple years old, so I wonder if it might be outdated, or more likely I just don't know what I'm doing.

A little more info. If I run

```
port installed opencv
```

I get

```
The following ports are currently installed:
  opencv @2.4.6_0+python27 (active)
```

So it looks like it's installed (?)

Comment: Have you tried `import cv2`?

Comment: I have, I get an ImportError for that as well

Comment: How about `import opencv.cv` or `from opencv import cv`, any of those worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled opencv, then did

```
sudo port install python27
sudo port install opencv +python27
sudo port select --set python python27
```

and it works